# Sentient sword seeks out modern man to fight ancient feud

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel in about 1980 about a guy who was sought out by a sentient sword (named Sapia? Sepia?) to continue an ancient feud. The guy was, unbeknownst to himself, a descendent of one warring faction and was being recruited to kill with the sentient sword descendants of the other warring faction. The sword communicated telepathically, but the man could shut the sword out of his mind temporarily when he wanted privacy as if closing a window blind in his mind. Anyone remember that?

Comment: When you say "modern man" do you mean that the story took place in a contemporary setting?  (i.e.  Late 20th century)  What country?

Comment: The story is set in the late 20th Century in the USA. The feud is thousands of years old. The man who is recruited by the sword was unaware of his lineage or if the feud. I think the sword could somehow sense if someone was a member of one or the other of these warring factions.

Comment: Sounds Moorcock-Eternal-Champion-ish.

Comment: No, not Moorcock. I was reading Moorcock at the same time, as well as Wielder of the White Gold stuff, but this was none of those.

Comment: As you can see, this is a tough one. Many hours have been wasted googling different word combinations in vain efforts to locate clues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*The Seeking Sword*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11542), by Jaan Kangilaski (1977). I no longer have a copy, but I reread it more than once and remember the plot. The protagonist is a contemporary man who becomes fascinated by a crude, ancient sword that is inhabited by the spirit of a prehistoric shaman. The shaman made the sword from meteoritic iron and entered it in order to defend his people against an invading tribe. Across thousands of years, the shaman/sword has enlisted one champion after another among his tribe's descendants, whom he recognizes by their "spirit flame," to kill the descendants of his enemies in a ritual stabbing. He can communicate telepathically -- when he feels like it. Unfortunately, when the enemy tribe conquered the shaman's tribe, they raped the women and so the descendants with friendly and enemy "flames" are mingled in the same families, whose members consequently keep alive the legends about the "Seeking Sword." A good deal of the book consists of the protagonist's quest to find documentary evidence of the Seeking Sword across the centuries. The shaman's name was quite long but a crucial part of it was Seppe, which means "smith" in Estonian, the language of the author's ancestors. Kangilaski wrote another book, *Hands of Glory* (1981), that uses the Seeking Sword as a character, but that one is set in medieval or Renaissance times.

Comment: You, Invisible Trihedron, are amazing. I immediately recognized the name when I read it in your post, and, as you can see, I mostly got the plot and even the Shaman’s name correct. I have ordered a copy from Abe Books for a paltry $4 and am looking forward to revisiting my memories from my 13 year old self. Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad the answer was still of service. I found the book curiously compelling although I wouldn't rate it as great literature. Please click on the checkmark to indicate that this is the correct answer.